# Need a wordpress shopping cart plugin for the following requirements in addition to the basic shop features. Any good suggestion?

Tags: php, wordpress, shopping-cart

I have a Wordpress site which need to be integrated with a shopping cart. The administrator dashboard should have all the below features in addition to the basic shop features. Please let me know your suggestions.

- The ability to print out orders daily for fulfillment
- Printing packing slips in batches
- Updating order status in batches
- Export shipping addresses
- Reporting on repeat customers and sales statistics by product, size and color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A constant challenge, integrating feature-rich ecommerce into WP.

Comment: My recommendation is to search for a developer who's good at wordpress and ask it to extend e-shop or some other that you think ot fits the most. Or, if this is too much for you, forget wordpress and go for a specialized cart script.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried one of the many shopping cart plugins? You might want to use one of them as a baseline and then get a good WordPress developer to enhance it with your requirements.

As an example, you might want to evaluate some of the plugins mentioned at
http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/16/the-ultimate-wordpress-shoppingecommerce-toolbox-plugins-and-themes/